# Hibernate Restrictions subquery with id of main query

Tags: java, hibernate

I got 2 Tables with data

```
Main
---
id          // 1

Second
---
id             //1; 2     
property       //"a"; "b"
creationDate(DD/MM/YYYY)   //01/01/2000; 02/02/2002
mainId         // 1; 1
```

The connection is 1-*
So, what I want to do is to query my "Main" table by the property in "Second", but I want to search only the newest property. 
So searching "a" must not give any result, as "b" is a newer data.

I wrota it via SQL and it looks like this:

```
select distinct m.id from Main m join Second s on m.id = s.mainId where s.property = 'b' and s.creationDate = (SELECT MAX(s2.creationDate) from Second s2 where s2.mainId = m.id);
```

I figured out some java code, but I have no idea how to use this `s2.mainId = m.id` part via Restrictions:

```
  DetachedCriteria d = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Second.class, "s1");
  ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
  proj.add(Projections.max("s1.creationDate"));
  d.setProjection(proj).add(Restrictions.eq("WHAT COMES HERE");
```

Or maybe should I use defferent approach?
Unformtunately I need to use Hibernate Criterion Interface as whole seach mechanismus is written via Criterion.

Answer (score 1):

```
    DetachedCriteria innerCrit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Second.class);
    innerCrit.setProjection(Projections.max("creationDate");
    innerCrit.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("id", "main.id"));

    DetachedCriteriaouterCrit outerCrit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Main.class, "main");
    outerCrit.createAlias("second", "second");
    outerCrit.add(Subqueries.eq(second.creationDate, innerCrit)); 
    outerCrit.add(Restrictions.eq("second.property", "b"));
```

This outerCrit will get you the Main object.